# Using Image tag in xaml with what type of property

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want to use an image in xaml with a `<Image></Image>` tag (Inside of a ListBox).

```
<Image  Source="{Binding ClassImage}"
        Width="64" Height="64"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Stretch="Fill"
        Margin="0,0,0,10"
        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
```

And using this constructor in the ViewModel.

```
public ChooseNewClassViewModel()
{
   ListOfModels = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
   foreach (var model in ListOfModels)
   {
       Model.ClassImage = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +     @"Common\Assets\Images\Image\" + PlayerClass.Name + ".png";
   }
}
```

And here is the Model property

```
public string ClassImage
{
     get { return _classImage; }
     set
     {
         _classImage = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ClassImage));
     }
}
```

Now, The `ClassImage` property is only a string property ( I read somewhere that it should work) but the images are not showing, but the rest of data I use in the view from `ListOfModels` works fine, and i can see three objects (empty) in the view from the list. 
The images in my Image folder are of type Resource and on copy if newer.

My question is I guess, whats the best way of binding the Image.Source property to what type of "property", is it the best way really to use a string? 
Whats the best way of using images you store in your project?

Comment: I'm so sorry, gonna update the question. Thats the ViewModels constructor. Removed other code to not confuse people with random stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your ChooseNewClassViewModel method (constructor?) doesn't do anything, because it first creates a list of models, then immediately iterates over the collection, but the collection is empty, because it hasn't been populated.

Perhaps you want your `ClassImage` property to look like this:

```
public string ClassImage
{
    get { return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory...; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that my xaml could not find the binding to my Model.
The quick way i fixed it is just i created a new string prop in my viewmodel, bound the xaml to that one instead and used it to show the images.

```
 public string ClassImage
        {
            get { return _classImage; }
            set
            {
                _classImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ClassImage));

            }
        }

 foreach (var PlayerClass in ListOfPlayerClasses)
            {

                ClassImage = @"/path/folders/" + PlayerClass.Name + ".png";
                PlayerClass.ClassImage = ClassImage;
            }
```